# Merge 2 different commit

Tags: git, version-control, push, commit

I already made a few changes on my commit and finalize my working copy, after that I did `git push` too.

But, suddenly I found a little problem on my modified files that has been already pushed to bitbucket repo. So, without undoing, I did manually changed my files into default for the first time. This is the workflow.

**C1**
README.md:
"`This is the content of the first readme on README.md`"

1. `git add README.md`
2. `git commit -m 'initialize README.md'`
3. `git push -u origin master`
4. DONE!

**C2**
after that, I updated my files into:
`The content is new on README.md`

1. like above
2. DONE!

**C3**
suddenly I made a few changes like these:
`This is the content of the first readme on README.md
add a few new lines
add a few new lines`

1. `git add README.md`
2. DONE!

I'm can't do commit on this state or I'll lose my **C2** changes. In this case, I wanna `git push` my **C3** and before I can continue my working copy, I wanna merge **C2** and **C3**, but only the "changes". So, in this case, would be like these:
`The content is new on README.md
add a few new lines
add a few new lines`

The question why I did this, because I forgot to work on `add a few lines` first before modifying "the first line".

I don't think `git revert` would do magic.
Thank you very much for your attention! :)

**EDIT**: `git cherry-pick` would also overwritten the local changes T___T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you rebase:

Step1: `$git rebase -i HEAD^^^`

This will take you to your default editor where your last two commits will be listed, swap them.

During rebase your C3 commit will become your 2nd commit C2' and C2 will become C3'.

So effectively these will your commits after resolving conflict during Rebase 2/2:

C1
README.md:
`This is the content of the first readme on README.md`

C2'
README.md:
`This is the content of the first readme on README.md`
`add a few new lines`
`add a few new lines`

C3'
README.md
`The content is new on README.md`
`add a few new lines`
`add a few new lines`

Now you will have to force push to your upstream.

`$git push -f -u origin master`

NOTE: It will overwrite your changes, you will have to tell others who have already fetched from you to do a force pull or fetch and merge/rebase.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Or if you don't want to rebase..(too many ppl have fetched your changes) then you can drop an branch at C2 and while on C3 do a `git merge C2-branch`

Comment: Thank you for your advice :). Btw, this error occurs when I tried `git rebase -i HEAD^^^`
"fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream HEAD^^^"

Comment: Sorry! My Bad! It must be `git rebase -i HEAD^^`

This is because rebase of first commit in a repository cannot be done. Its needs atleast a single commit for revision.

This is the reason I create a 0th commit in every repository of mine, this 0th commit is an empty commit.

Comment: For EMPTY_COMMIT method you can check this out:
https://github.com/mudassirazvi/EMPTY_COMMIT.git

Its explained why this is necessary!

Comment: I see :D I'll remember this, to create 0th commit before any commit for my next development :) Thank you very much sir, this is awesome!

Comment: According your github [here](https://github.com/mudassirazvi/EMPTY_COMMIT.git), `empty commit` would take place to last head right? or this commit would be take place to the first commit?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by 'take place to last/first head/commit! Please be a bit more clear! :)

Comment: Sorry for my bad english sir t(^_^) I meant, is `empty commit` will be the 1st commit before **C1**?

Comment: Yes! The Empty Commit will be the first commit. C1 will come above it! :)

Comment: Sir, thanks again for your help :) I did `git commit --allow-empty` http://imgur.com/62EUKEA but the **0th commit** didn't override **C1** commit?

Comment: Hahaha. I guess you got me wrong. --allow-empty will just create an empty commit. you have to make it the 0th commit.

1. Create a new repo and make the 0th commit.
2. From your old repo create patches if ur C1 and C2 commits using (git format-patch)
3. In your new repo apply these 2 patches over 0th commit.(git am)

Now you are good to go!